# How can I save Mongoose in sync mode?

Tags: mongoose

When I save 4 record, I need to save them one by one, so my code is

```
a.save(function(){
 b.save(function(){
  c.save(function(){
   d.save(function(){
   }
  }
 }
}
```

How can I write code like

```
a.save();
b.save();
c.save();
d.save();
```

and make the save in sync mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really make sync mode of a moongoose (or anything else with db) as the node.js is not made in that way. But there are two ways to make it easier or more clean.

If all 4 records are the same model, than you can create array of this elements and use Moognoose insertMany (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany). If not, you can use async library (http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html). In this case, your code would look like:

```
var objArr = [a, b, c, d];
async.each(objArr, function(object, callback){
    object.save(function(err){
        if(err) { 
            callback(err)
        }
        else { 
            callback() 
        }
    });
}, function (err){
    if(err) { 
        //if any of your save produced error, handle it here
    } 
    else {
        // no errors, all four object should be in db
    }
});
```

Comment: I think async is what i need. my models can't use insert many